# TimeMachine MacOS copy just one folder from another Mac

Tags: mac, permissions

I have an old TimeMachine backup from a previous MacBook. In that backup is one specific folder I want to be copied on my new MacBook. I tried it with Migration Assistent, but that doesn't allow you to pick one specific folder without migrating other things as well.

If I manually move that folder from the HDD to the new MacBook, I get permission errors.

If I check the permissions via `ls -l` I get on the folder the following:

> `drwxr-xr-x@  84 my-username  staff  2688  5 dec  2020 TheCopiedFolder`

Looks good to me... but when I try to save, I get the error that I don't have enough permission.
I tried via Finder permissions of the folder, to reconfigure it, but without any luck.

Other folders - who are working correctly - have this permissions:

> `drwx------+   9 my-username  staff   288 13 nov  2020 Movies`

Can someone tell me what I have to do, to get the rights correctly?

I also tried it via the console:
`chmod -R 705 TheCopiedFolder && chmod -R 705  TheCopiedFolder/*`
But still.. the rights aren't changed when I run `ls -l`.

Comment: The "+" in the permissions list (and maybe the "@") indicate these items have access controls as well as traditional permissions. Use `ls -leO@` to add ACLs, flags, and extended attributes to the listing (ACLs are probably the problem here, but it doesn't hurt to check flags and xattrs as well).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this, but this is a very Time Machine-specific issue, more akin to quarantine than standard nix perms…

It's not really a perms issue you fix with traditional unix tools, it's a whole slew of perms very Time Machine specific.
To bypass it, you need to remove ACLs, or add one, which you can actually do from 'Get Info' by just adding your current admin account, once the drive is no longer directly under Time Machine's control.
If Time Machine doesn't think it's still in control - i.e. if it doesn't recognise it as an inherited drive, then you should be able to check the "Ignore ownership on this volume" in Get Info, which might get you in even faster.

Time Machine doesn't want you as a user to have full control over the drive, so adding yourself as full control should then let you just drag & drop in Finder.